# Posting image to Facebook album with AS3 API

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-as3-api

I'm having trouble with posting an image from my canvas application to the user's albums.  According to the Facebook docs:

> In order to publish a photo to a user’s album, you must have the publish_stream permission. With that granted, you can upload a photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional description to one these to Graph API connections:
>
> 1. https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos - The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded this way will then be added to this same album.
> 2. https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos - The photo will be published to a specific, existing photo album, represented by the ALBUM_ID.

So, going by point one, if I upload an image like this...

```
Facebook.api("me/photos",imagePostCallback,{message:"",image:myImageBitmap,fileName:''},URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

...then I can expect it to place my image in an album named for my app, which it will create if necessary?

**Not so**.

What actually happens when the album doesn't exist is that the uploaded image is pushed into any other handy albums that exist, which are usually for (and created by) other applications.  This is a bit of a pain.

So far I've tried the following:

1. Disabling sandbox mode. I had thought that the app might be unable to create new albums because it was in sandbox mode, however disabling sandbox mode made no difference and I can create albums directly with it enabled.
2. Checking for the existence of my album and creating it if necessary.  I can check for my album and create it if it does not exist, but I cannot then upload an image because the POST call to `Facebook.api` to upload the image will fail if it is not called as a direct result of a user interaction.

And so now I'm a bit stumped. Obviously I can't have the possibility of my app posting images to a competitors album, but at the moment the only alternative I can see will involve effectively making the user submit their image twice if an album has to be created.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to accomplish this?  I have a similar problem I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815103/as3-facebook-canvas-app-need-to-post-image-to-friends-feed-wall-can-it-be

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you need the access_token in your params :) When posting something on a user's facebook, you always need this one (not always necessary when getting information). The way to get the accesstoken is shown below :)

```
public function post():void
{
    var _params:Object = new Object();

    _params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
    _params.message = "";
    _params.image = myImageBitmap;
    _params.fileName = "";

    Facebook.api("me/photos", imagePostCallback, _params, URLRequestMethod.POST);
}
```

also make sure that you have the right permissions when asking for permissions with your app.

**EDIT**

Ok, so I've missed your edit a bit there ;) it should be possible to create your own album. Take a look at this php-code for graph api. The code should also be able to be parsed to AS3.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

**EDIT2**

ok, i've done some more digging (seemed interesting to know). This should actually work when using graph api.

```
FB.api('/me/albums', albumCreateCallback, {name: 'name of the album', message: 'description of the album'}, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

When you then call for another api call to upload your image in the albumCreateCallback, it should work and upload your image (according to what i've found).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Definitely not a permissions/access_token issue I'm afraid.  The image does post, just not to it's own album as it's supposed to.  I'm already running a check for the existence of the album and creating it if required, but as I mentioned in the question this can't happen on the user interaction because then the image post will not be seen as a direct result of user interaction. I've opted for creating the album silently earlier in the application if it doesn't already exist, but this has the potential for an empty album to be left if the user chooses not to submit.

Comment: is there some event that is fired when your app is closed? maybe you could then check if the album is empty and if so, remove it again? :)

Comment: I suppose that might be possible if I get the offline_access permission as well...