# AS3 Facebook canvas app - need to post image to friend's feed (wall) - can it be done?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I have a Facebook canvas app, written in AS3, and using the Adobe Facebook API.

I can connect, get a list of friends, pick a friend, all that stuff is working fine.  The problem is when I try and post to a friend's wall.  I am trying to post an image.  That's it, just an image.

The image is 200x200, which meets the facebook guidlines of not being smaller than 50x50 and outside of a 3:1 ratio.

I have searched all over the interwebz for an answer and have tried all examples I can find.  I have cobbled together what looked like promising attempts, only to have the image still not show up.  Other info, like the message, link etc, do show up if I include it.  Just no picture.  Here is the code that looked the most promising based on what facebook docs say.

```
Facebook.api('/' + friendID  +'/feed', onPicPosted, {image:imageToPost, message:messageToPost, fileName:'FILE_NAME'}, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

**friendID** is the selected friend, **imageToPost** is a bitmap, **onPicPosted** is the callback, which returns successful, even though the image does not show up.

I have also tried a slight variation based on someone's suggestion, changing **image** to **picture** in the params object.

```
Facebook.api('/' + friendID  +'/feed', onPicPosted, {picture:imageToPost, message:messageToPost, fileName:'FILE_NAME'}, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

permissions have been properly requested and granted ('publish_stream', and also 'user_photos' and 'friends_photos' just for safe measure).

This issue is delaying a delivery so it is urgent I figure this out.  If anyone has an idea of how to accomplish posting an image (bitmap, created in flash) to a selected friend's wall, please help!  Thanks!

Comment: In these examples, what is `imageToPost`?

Comment: imageToPost is a bitmap, created in flash by taking a "snapshot" of a movieclip and turning it into bitmapData.  And that is the big question here:  is it possible to upload to a friend's wall a bitmap, dynamically created in AS3, from a facebook canvas app written in Flash - or any other way in fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research:

This is not possible.  **image** is not a property expected, rather **picture** is, and **picture** expects a url as its value not a bitmap.

The solution was to first upload the image to a server via php, then post the image with the returned url.

Also, as a side note, an image posted to a friend's wall via an app can be no larger than 90x90.  It can be larger than that if posted to the user's own wall, but not to the user's friends' walls.