# Facebook login on Adobe AIR for Desktop

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air, desktop-application

I have some question about Facebook SDK system.
My app work on a computer (Adobe AIR).

But I want to connect with Facebook , login , post to wall and logout.

In the past it's work fine. But now, it's not working. And everything about Facebook developer console has changed a lot.

I've 3 questions to ask

1. How to setting my apps for Desktop application?
2. Which way is the best for connect with Facebook?
3. If I don't have "ssl server" , can I work on localhost?

Thank you so much

Comment: please share with us what you tried and where exactly you encountered obstacles. This is not a 'write-my-code' site.

Comment: @planetmaker, I think they want advice on the 3 points asked... no code even necessary to see or write. Just advice.

Comment: @netzerodash, does `post to wall` mean just share links? Otherwise I dont think they let outside apps make status updates. Imagine if some computer virus started writing things on your facebook wall for you... the only option is to share links to some web page. You search this site or Google.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for your answer. About "Post to wall" I mean the user can post the photo to their wall via my AIR Application.

Comment: The photo will have to exist on a server somewhere. Either  **(1)** Its a link to an online photo location (your app could upload to your server via php then also post url link of that image to facebook) or **(2)** Make your app upload to user's photo album then also search album for newest upload to share on wall.

Comment: Consider these links **[Photo upload AS3 demo](http://snipplr.com/view/63016/upload-image-to-facebook-using-graphapiwebswc-in-as3/)**, you should have that **[SWC](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc&can=2&q=)**. Also maybe this **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611685/posting-image-to-facebook-album-with-as3-api)** and also the **[OpenGraph docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo)** can help you..

Comment: @VC.One Thanks you so much. Now I've use javascript for working with Facebook and use StageWebView to connect between my apps and javascript. And about share photo to wall , I've use sharer.php and change photo with dynamic html .Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: +1 for using **sharer.php**. (I forgot about that one). When you can, you should put that info as actual Answer since others might be looking for it also. Justy briefly explain the process and the dynamic html for image updates trick.

Comment: Hi @VC.One I've shared my trick already. Many thanks for you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've working with javascript API.

:: Step ::
1. Use manual login via load HTML on this URL and redirect to your page
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&type=user_agent&redirect_url=YOUR_PAGE

2. add "LOCATION_CHANGE" event listener after YOUR_PAGE is open. YOUR_PAGE must call Login UI from javascript API.
3. AFTER login you must check "LOCATION_CHANGE" again.
4. IF location change, redirect to sharer.php to share your page.

YOUR PAGE MUST BE A DYNAMIC HTML

Upload your photo to server and send the file's name to javascript function on Dynamic HTML. And generate meta data for Facebook Sharer.

*This is a starter step. If you want to work with your virtual keyboard or work with javascript function. Learn about Focus Event and HTML_BOUNDS_CHANGE

Thank you everyone....
and many thanks for @VC.One